# Is it possible to use antd with create-react-app 2?

Tags: create-react-app, antd

My understanding is react-app-rewired no longer works in v2 of create-react-app.

It seems you need to get into babel (thus react-app-rewired).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [craco](https://github.com/sharegate/craco) instead of react-app-rewired.

Information from [react-app-rewired issue comments](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/162#issuecomment-436120752):

> Here are some example craco.config.js configuration files:
>
> [Less](https://github.com/sharegate/craco/blob/00ae1a4364bfbe5b1ef7d5f5d89affc030c46c1f/recipes/use-less-loader/craco.config.js)
>   [Ant Design + Less + modifyVars](https://github.com/sharegate/craco/blob/0c35cc366ea79250e31f161172014b6a7107e3d3/recipes/use-ant-design/craco.config.js)
>   [Ant Design + Less + modifyVars + Preact](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/162#issuecomment-436120752)
>   [Preact](https://github.com/sharegate/craco/blob/d503f663bf8cfa9e222d37f180b49ae4c2d082ca/recipes/use-preact/craco.config.js)
>
> There are [some more examples in the /recipes directory in the craco repo](https://github.com/sharegate/craco/tree/master/recipes).

Example of `craco.config.js` from [ndbroadbent](https://github.com/ndbroadbent):

```
const CracoAntDesignPlugin = require('craco-antd');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const WebpackBar = require('webpackbar');

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: { react: 'preact-compat', 'react-dom': 'preact-compat' },
    plugins: [
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
      new WebpackBar({ profile: true }),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [{ plugin: CracoAntDesignPlugin }],
};
```